# openInMapsWithLaunchOptions not working?

Tags: swift, ios8, mapkit

I'm passing in options for the map, but this does not seem to do anything with the zoom level?? It keeps the same low zoom level.
 What have I missed?

```
func openMapForPlace() {
    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    var coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(detailItem!.geoLatitude, detailItem!.geoLongitude)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    var options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]
    var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = detailItem!.cityName
    mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
}
```

Comment: Nope, I went for a in app map.

Comment: Yes, it does not seem to work on the Maps app once a mapItem has been added. There are a few threads with the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple's documentation does not mention it but from testing, it seems like `openInMapsWithLaunchOptions()` seems to ignore the `MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey` option if one or more `MKMapItem` are added to the map.

The following code works as expected, with the map zoom being adjusted properly when the distance parameter is modified (try with 1000 and 10000000, to see the difference):

```
func openMapForPlace() {
    let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 10000000
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40, 0)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]

    MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([], launchOptions: options)
}
```

However, as soon as one `MKMapItem` is added to the map, the zoom stops working.

```
func openMapForPlace() {
    let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 10000000
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40, 0)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "Test"

    MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([mapItem], launchOptions: options)
}
```