# How to open maps App programmatically with coordinates in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

I have latitude and longitude that I want to open into my map application. I tried this code from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504294/programmatically-open-maps-app-in-ios-6).

```
    func goToMap(){

    var lat1 : NSString = self.venueLat
    var lng1 : NSString = self.venueLng

    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    var placemark : MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil)

    var mapItem:MKMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)

    mapItem.name = "Target location"

    let launchOptions:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, forKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey)

    var currentLocationMapItem:MKMapItem = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()

    MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([currentLocationMapItem, mapItem], launchOptions: launchOptions)

}
```

This function successfully open maps but it doesn't show any pin. Also it shows user location which I don't want. I only want a pin on the map for the provided latitude and longitude.

Comment: This code is intended to show driving directions from the user location to the target.  To just show a single target, use MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey and a single map item.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427557/openinmapswithlaunchoptions-not-working.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

This code is working fine for me.

```
func openMapForPlace() {
    
    let lat1 : NSString = self.venueLat
    let lng1 : NSString = self.venueLng
    
    let latitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
    let longitude:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue
    
    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "\(self.venueName)"
    mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
    
}
```

For swift 3.0:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        openMapForPlace()
    }
    
    func openMapForPlace() {
        
        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 37.2
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 22.9
        
        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
        let options = [
            MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
            MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
        ]
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "Place Name"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
    }
}
```

Swift 5:

```
let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = Double(K.latitude)!
let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = Double(K.longitude)!
let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: regionDistance, longitudinalMeters: regionDistance)
let options = [
    MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
    MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
]
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapItem.name = K.companyName
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey option has the desired effect? No matter what value I use for CLLocationDistance, the map is zoomed in pretty closely.

Comment: It seems that the `MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey` is ignored when one or more `MKMapItem` are added to the map: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32484331/422288

Comment: Don't forget: import MapKit

Comment: Just wanted to point out that it's "latitude" and "longitude" not "latitute" and "longitute" although "tute" is funnier

Comment: if the user have removed the maps application that how can we check on that case???

Comment: `import MapKit` and `import CoreLocation` too!

Comment: @kbunarjo, why do we require to import `CoreLocation`?

Comment: @AmritTiwari 
Good question.. A very clear explanation to this is given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603120/how-to-check-if-apple-maps-is-installed

Comment: i am trying to implement lets hope for the best.

Comment: It looks like will work like a charm and even it says "Directions" but once I tap there it says, directions not available. AND my country is on the supported list.

Answer (score 80):

If you just want to give the user driving directions, here's the latest Swift syntax in its simplest form:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theLatitude,theLongitude)
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
mapItem.name = "Target location"
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
```

Comment: This worked well for me, except that the key and value are reversed in the launch options.  Should be `mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions([MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])`

Comment: Make sure to add import MapKit to top of the file to resolve errors.

Comment: Also in swift 3 the last line is now... mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])

Answer (score 55):

You could call class function of `MKMapItem` passing items there, it uses only first and last for source / destination appropriately, if you want pass more than two items.

### Swift 5, 4

```
let source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)))
source.name = "Source"
        
let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)))
destination.name = "Destination"
        
MKMapItem.openMaps(
  with: [source, destination], 
  launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
)
```

or using extension:

```
extension MKMapItem {
  convenience init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String) {
    self.init(placemark: .init(coordinate: coordinate))
    self.name = name
  }
}

let source = MKMapItem(coordinate: .init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng), name: "Source")
let destination = MKMapItem(coordinate: .init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng), name: "Destination")

MKMapItem.openMaps(
  with: [source, destination], 
  launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
)
```

Comment: hi dimpiax! Thanks for your answer, didn't test it but seems pretty ok. Is it possible to send several waypoints? How!? Can you please help me.

Comment: @Frade hey, with MapKit you cannot, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452207-openmaps

But you can achieve it using Google Maps.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, minutes after. Thanks

Answer (score 40):

The `MKMapItem` approach above works great if you want granular control over the information that is displayed in Maps.

Otherwise, the code below works great as well, :

```
// Open and show coordinate
let url = "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=\(coord.latitude),\(coord.longitude)"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:url)!)

// Navigate from one coordinate to another
let url = "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=\(from.latitude),\(from.longitude)&daddr=\(to.latitude),\(to.longitude)"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:url)!)
```

However, the code above does not let you to send in a custom name of the place. Instead, it will show the address.

The code above also lets you navigate from any source coordinate, which I don't know if you can do with the MKMapItem approach.

Comment: If you leave "saddr=" blank, the app would set "your location" as default. Something like "http:// maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=\(to.latitude),\(to.longitude)"

Comment: directions not available

Answer (score 13):

This works as a charm for me

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theLatitude, theLongitude)
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.02))
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
let options = [
    MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: region.center),
    MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: region.span)]
mapItem.name = theLocationName
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
```

Comment: This is no longer working me. I ended up with "No directions available."

Answer (score 5):

You can use below code to show PIN on lat, long in to Apple map.

```
let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.848854,144.990295)

let regionSpan =   MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, 1000, 1000)

let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)

let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)

mapItem.name = “Desired place”

mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions:[
MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center)
] as [String : Any])
```

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is something simple without importing any framework you can just create a URL: `https://maps.apple.com/?ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)`

Is similar to @saniel-saidi response but this one opens just the map with location sent, not the navigation thing

Comment: just remove () around coordinates, does not find it with them.

Answer (score 3):

Update to the practical Daniel Saidi [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251592/2129178). This example is for telling only the destination coordinates. Maps will get as origin the user current position.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=\(lat),\(lon)")
UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know all answers are complete but here I got an answer which is easier to copy paste & also gives the user options to routing with Apple Maps, Google Map & Waze.

Working with **Swift 5+**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60930491/6449292

Might help someone...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to open the Apple Maps app and show a pin on the custom location with a custom title is that:

```
let url = URL(string: "maps://?q=Title&ll=\(latitude),\(longitude)")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Look here for more options:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: Note: remember to escape the q=<Title> or the whole string otherwise the url will fail crashing.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5 Solution:

**Open Apple Map OR Google Map Programmatically**

```
  let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Open Location", message: "Choose an app to open direction", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    // Pass the coordinate inside this URL
                    self.openGoogleMap()
                }))
                actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Maps", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                    // Pass the coordinate that you want here
                    self.openAppleMap()
                }))
                actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

//Function defination here


func openAppleMap(){
        guard let lat = bookingData.gpsLatitude, let latDouble =  Double(lat) else {return }
        guard let long = bookingData.gpsLongitude, let longDouble =  Double(long) else {return }
        
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latDouble,longDouble)
                    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
                    mapItem.name = "Destination"
                    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
    }
    


func openGoogleMap() {
            guard let lat = bookingData.gpsLatitude, let latDouble =  Double(lat) else {return }
            guard let long = bookingData.gpsLongitude, let longDouble =  Double(long) else {return }
            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {  //if phone has an app
                
                if let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=&daddr=\(latDouble),\(longDouble)&directionsmode=driving") {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
                }}
            else {
                //Open in browser
                if let urlDestination = URL.init(string: "https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/?saddr=&daddr=\(latDouble),\(longDouble)&directionsmode=driving") {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(urlDestination)
                }
            }
        }
```

**Don't forget to write this in info.plist**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps-x-callback</string>
    </array>
```