# iOS Simulator Maps not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to get a map up and running in one of my apps and for some reason, maps are not working at all. In my app, I just get a blank image of the grid that shows when maps load and it never loads the map.

I tried running the stock Apple Maps app on the simulator, as well, and I am having the same problem.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes iOS Simulator loses internet connectivity. Killing the simulator and running the application again solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure Location is enable from

Simulator options Features->Location->Apple

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have followed the following steps:

1. MapView in Interface Builder, connect the map view to the `MapView` controller swift file.
2. Just above the `mapcenterpinimage` property. A popup will appear; set the connection type to Outlet and the name to `MapView`.
3. Once you have created the Outlet, request the user location, i.elet l`ocationManager = CLLocationManager()`
4. `View did load` call these code

locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

You can also follow the below tutorial link, which I found to be very useful. http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift  could be pl. checkout the below stack overflow I have details to support, apple map in Swift.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use Google Maps.

Comment: Kelsey, could be pl. checkout the below stack overflow i has details to support, apple map in swift. link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604429/how-to-open-maps-app-programatically-with-coordinates-in-swift?rq=1. Hope it helps you.