# Apple map display name

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-maps

I am developing a hybrid app using Ionic and I am able to open apple map app with the URL that look like this: `maps://?q=1.5149818510303,110.35436153412`

How can I get the apple map to display the shop name at the marker?

Comment: use `mkmapitem` class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604429/how-to-open-maps-app-programatically-with-coordinates-in-swift

Comment: AFAIK you have to use a plugin for that. I don't know a way to extend the map query for enabling additional map infos.

Answer (score 1):

`q` param is the query to search and you can't control the text displayed, but you can use `ll` to specify the location (latitude and longitude), and then the `q` param will be used as label for the pin

```
maps://?ll=1.5149818510303,110.35436153412&q=test
```

[read here all the allowed params](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

```
q
```

> The q parameter can also be used as a label if the location is
>   explicitly defined in the ll or address parameters.

```
ll
```

> The location around which the map should be centered.
>
> The ll parameter can also represent a pin location when you use the q
>   parameter to specify a name.